# Current Transformer noise in idle state

Tags: current, stm32, current-measurement, single-supply-op-amp

[[image: ***Violet is the bias voltage. Yellow is the CT output. You can it drifting from bias voltage a little. Thats my STM32 detecting as a Load***]**strong text**[1]]
***Violet is the bias voltage. Yellow is the CT output. You can see it drifting from bias volt a little. ***

I want to build a power measurement circuit using STM32F407. I am using LM324N opamp for the current transformer. The circuit is working fine. But the issue is when there is no load at the current transformer, it’s drifting form the bias voltage a little around 1.68 to 1.63. And my STM32 detecting that as a load current.

The picture is when there is around 40 A load at current transformer.
BLUE- BIAS VOLT 1.65V YELLOW - CT OUTPUT  RED- 230 VOLT WAVEFORM(Ignore that)[image: BLUE- BIAS VOLT 1.65V YELLOW - CT OUTPUT RED- 230 VOLT WAVEFORM(Ignore that)]

And please tell if there any improvement I can do with the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqfGb5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What happens if you divide R_SRC, R3 and R4 by 10?

Comment: I didnt wanted to use R3 as 1Kilo Ohm. Cause i want to measure 3 phase. So from that bias volt there are 5 opamp circuit taking bias Volt from it. 3 for Current,and 3 for Volt Measurement. @Jeroen3 Do you think if i use 1k in R3,it will not effect the other opamp circuits ?

Comment: Why no 10k after R_SRC1 to balance differential? Why C3 on output? Is it that noisy?  Why 100 Ohms?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I didnt know that,Ok i will try to use another 10k after R_SRC1.      The C3 is only to stable the Bias Volt. Its not noisy.It is coming from a Linear Regulator.

Comment: 10k to Vdd/2 to Vin- and Vin + on  OA1 makes it  a linear Diff Amp of gain =30

Comment: Better for CMR if balanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3 is the problem. Connecting a capacitor to the output of an opamp makes it oscillate. Take it out.